# Unable to Create Lambda Authorizer Using API Gateway WebSocket Console, Error: Unexpected Key 'ProviderArns' Found in Params

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I cannot add a lambda authorizer to my WebSocket API from the AWS Console.

When I click the `Create` button, I get a red error banner at the top with the error: `Unexpected key 'ProviderArns' found in params` and nothing happens.

I've even tried creating a blank test WebSocket API and a blank test Lambda function, but I still get this error when creating a a new authorizer. I have tried every combination of having or not having `Lambda Invoke Roles` or `Identity Sources`, but I still get this error.

[image: Console Error]

This was all working yesterday, but my authorizers spontaneously stopped working today, and I haven't been able to add/edit them. I have since added a CloudWatch log role for logging, but even when I remove this, all my webSockets are still broken.

The authorizers in my REST APIs are still working just fine and I can add/delete/edit these authorizers with no problem.

Does anyone know what's going on or at least how to fix/circumvent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to circumvent these errors by creating an authorizer using the [AWS-CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/create-authorizer.html). After creating the authorizer using the CLI, the online console is working again too. I guess this can be chocked up to a bug somewhere in APIGateway and/or the web console.